# AndroidSwipeLayout swipe different action

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

in my project i use [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout), but i can use only one swipe method.
Whether it is possible to add another action?
I'd like something like that:
[image]

Comment: Possibly recycler view?

Comment: Use Swipe gesture class

Comment: any way to make the listview like gmail ;)

Comment: @AmnaMirza i should use it for listview or for my adapter?
Can i use tabs for item in my listview?

Comment: @Pionas for adapter probably